# Dependency [openrave] cannot be found

Tags: ros, roscreate-pkg, openrave, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed ros-electric and openrave on my ubuntu 10.04, and I'm trying to create a package "grasp" by the command as follow

```
  roscreate-pkg grasp openrave roscpp
```

and I turns out

```
  bcddivad@bcddivad-laptop:~/code/ros/openravecode$ roscreate-pkg grasp openrave roscpp
  ERROR: dependency [openrave] cannot be found
  bcddivad@bcddivad-laptop:~/code/ros/openravecode$
```

can anyone please help me ?

---

post edited

I installed openrave by the commands given on the website [here](http://openrave.programmingvision.com/en/main/install.html#install)

```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openrave/release
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install openrave
```

Do I have to do anything else to let ros to include the openrave library?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32330/dependency-%5Bopenrave%5D-cannot-be-found/) by [bcddivad](https://answers.ros.org/users/2223/bcddivad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2012-04-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bcddivad](https://answers.ros.org/users/2223/bcddivad/) on 2012-04-27**:
I edited my original post, how can I solve it?

**Comment by [bcddivad](https://answers.ros.org/users/2223/bcddivad/) on 2012-04-27**:
I installed Openrave with thte instruction on the web site, will there be a package for openrave? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess you didn't install openrave. For electric, there doesn't seem to be a debian package containing the openrave ros package. There is a ros package [here] though (http://ros.org/wiki/openrave).

Normally, openrave doesn't really need to be a ros package to be used in your ros nodes. You can remove the dependency on openrave in manifest.xml and install it from a PPA as explained [here](http://openrave.programmingvision.com/en/main/install.html#install).

**Edit**: According to [this](http://openrave.programmingvision.com/en/coreapihtml/writing_plugins.html) page you need to add something like the following to your ROS package's CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package(OpenRAVE REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenRAVE_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${OpenRAVE_LIBRARY_DIRS})
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2